# Transpiled version of JavaScript code in node_modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, compilation, node-modules, es5-compatiblity

quick question.
From what I read, when publishing you package to npm repository, you have to compile your TypeScript files to JavaScript. But what about the version (es5, es6) it should be transpiled to ? What if I transpile my package to es6, and then someone who uses (includes) this package in his project as dependency and uses let's say es5 as target in his project ? How to handle this ? does he has to to transpile my library package in his node_modules from es6 to es5 ? Also, I found In some webpack projects that they exclude node_modules in webpack.config.js from transpilation.

I tried researching this on google, however couldn't find any relevant information.

Comment: it depends on who your target consumer is

Comment: Compile your library to the lowest EcmaScript version that you want to support. Consumers of your library that use a higher version can still use your library.